# Configuring Single Sign-On Authentication via SAML 2.0

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on

We are trying to configure Single Sign-On Authentication via SAML 2.0. We have tried with two different XML metadata, one of them the example given for ExactTarget in WEB and other XML created by us. In both case, we have received different error.
Could anybody give us the correct xml structure, that the application is waiting?
Thank you very much

Comment: Can you post a gist with the xml?

Comment: Can you put this somewhere we can actually see it properly, and delete the comments.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1EBHQJZR2PRbTFIWWh1TmpwRm8/view?usp=sharing